# Scrapy x path: Loop over two different blocks and combine results

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping this website: https://www.mrlodge.de/wohnungen/
Therefore I wrote a crawler which works great and extracts all information from each offer. Each offer also has detailed information. This detailed information I can reach with the url returned by this xpath expression:

`x = listings.xpath('//form/input[@name="name_url"]/@value').getall()`

The problem I am facing is that it is inside the offer block but not inside the div tags which I am already looping. I have tried the following but I only get the first element for detail_url. There has to be a way to include it inside the for loop but I just don't get how.

Please help

```
def parse(self, response):
    json_response = json.loads(response.body)
    listings = Selector(text=json_response.get('list'))
    x = listings.xpath('//form/input[@name="name_url"]/@value').get()

    for listing in listings.xpath("//div[@class='mrlobject-list__item__content']"):
        yield {
            'title': listing.xpath('.//div[@class="obj-smallinfo"]/text()').get(),
            'rent': listing.xpath(".//span[@class='obj-rent']/text()").get(),
            'room': listing.xpath(".//span[@class='obj-room']/text()").get(),
            'area': listing.xpath(".//span[@class='obj-area']/text()").get(),
            'info': listing.xpath(".//div[@class='object-title']/text()").get(),
            'detail_url': x
        }
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of what is the "detailed information" for the first listing on the page?

Comment: The detail_url is: /wohnen-auf-zeit/2-zimmer-wohnung-muenchen-schwabing-11651 so the "detailed information" would be everything which is found at the URL: url+detail_url. There I need only the postalcode. First though I need to get all the url extensions for each listing

Comment: "url_extension" is probably better suited as a name for "detailed_url" I guess

Comment: Doesn't the xpath expression `//form/input[@name="name_url"]/@value` get you a list of all "url_extensions" which you can loop through?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: So what's exactly is the problem?